# Write spark partitions to different S3 paths

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have a spark job running. I want to write partitions to different s3 folders.
Consider there are 5 partitions in the data frame. I want to write partition 1 to s3 path 1, partition 2 to s3 path 2 and so on. Is this possible to achieve in spark?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you are using Hive metastore. Wrote this example using local filesystem but it works with S3 as well. First, let's create some directories

```
mkdir -p /tmp/foo/p0
mkdir -p /tmp/foo/bar/p1
```

Then run the following PySpark snippet:

```
from pyspark import Row
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .config('hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode', 'nonstrict')\
    .enableHiveSupport()\
    .getOrCreate()

spark.sql('create database if not exists foo')
spark.sql('create table if not exists foo.bar (y int) partitioned by (x int)')
spark.sql("alter table foo.bar add if not exists partition (x=0) location 'file:/tmp/foo/p0/'")
spark.sql("alter table foo.bar add if not exists partition (x=1) location 'file:/tmp/foo/bar/p1'")

spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(y=0, x=0), Row(y=0, x=1)
]).write.insertInto('foo.bar')
```

The partitions have now been written into the defined custom locations:

```
ls /tmp/foo/p0
part-00003-06e0fc37-c542-495d-acdc-20d1631ba095.c000
ls /tmp/foo/bar/p1
part-00007-06e0fc37-c542-495d-acdc-20d1631ba095.c000
```